# Usage of "Trying" in a sentence to declare an attempt + will

Tags: spoken-english, conversation

I was going to move to a new house and I told my colleague that "during the weekend, I was trying to move to my new place", he responded by saying "trying? So are you moving or not?". Both of us are not native English speakers!! So, I wanted to ask if what I said is correct or should have rather said "I am moving" instead of "I am trying to move"?

To add, what does "trying" signifies in the following sentences:

1. I am trying to listen to the radio.
2. I am trying to work on my essay.

Does it mean that "I am willing or wanting" or does it mean "I am actively doing something"? Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

The word "trying" in your context is closer to "attempting". Listener wouldn't know whether or not you have succeeded or not, because you were only "trying". If that's the case, you might want to provide more context to why the task has not been completed.

If you really have moved, you should say "I moved to my new place".

Answer (score 0):

Trying is the verb form of [Try](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/try):

When used in a sentence it usually means that the person is actively attempting to do something, but not immediately succeeding.

> Trying to listen to the radio

Means that they are attempting to hear the music/voices, but something is stopping them from doing so.

If instead you wanted to say that the person is willing or wanting to do something, but hasn't yet started, you could use "looking".

> I am looking to move house

Here this would mean that the person is interested in moving, but has yet to actually start the process